# How to count multiple column from same table in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a database where there are 5 columns with integer values
i wanna know the total value of those column. I cant seem to figure out how to do it nor in sql nor in sequelize. i tried sum but i cant sum multiple column.

SELECT COUNT(price)
FROM Transaction;

I know i can do this for 1 column in sql also i want to know how to do it on sequelize?

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
"select SUM(IFNULL(`column1`, 0) + IFNULL('column2`, 0) + IFNULL(`column3`, 0)) AS total from transaction order by total asc";
```

change column1, column2 etc with your actual column names

#### EDIT

```
"select sum(price) as price1, sum(sale) as sale1, sum(quantity) as quantity1 from transaction";
```

Comment: thank you but it is not quite what i want... maybe my bad english confused you.. i was hoping to add columns individually  and get their sum... for example if i have columns with price , sale i want my sql to give me sum of price and sum of sale

Comment: thank you so much :) do you have any idea how to do it in sequelize